# add custom Names space in wsdl generated from Apex soap webservice class

Tags: soap-api, xml, apex-webservice

requirement: i need to expose the Soap service(from salesforce) and give the wsdl to client to consume/call my service.

1. created global Apex class and webservice method :

   ```
   global with sharing class mycustomsoapservice{
    webservice static void updatemycontact(String firstName, String lastName){
         String greetMessage = 'Welcome '+firstName+' '+lastName;             
      }
    }
   ```
2. download the WSDL from above Apex class and provide to clinet.

**WSDL**

```
<definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/mycustomsoapservice" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/mycustomsoapservice">
<types>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/mycustomsoapservice">
 ......
```

but my client expects specific Namespace in wsdl(which i provide) to call my Apex webservice method.

**client expecting in wsdl**

> xmlns:tns="http://cbc.edu/mycustomsoapservice"

**instead of**

> xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/mycustomsoapservice"

is it possible? Please help on this

Comment: It is not possible to alter the target namespace of the generated WSDL. Generally speaking you shouldn't need to as consumer will adapt to the WSDL as required.

Comment: thank you @DanielBallinger  for quick response.